# Selenium log hide in python

Tags: python, api, selenium, rest, automation

How to disable selenium logs and hide browser popup

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

output:

```
[WDM] - 

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 95.0.4638
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 95.0.4638
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\test\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\95.0.4638.54\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
dem.py:7: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9739/devtools/browser/c8ded71b-7f57-41c4-b27a-41db09694c06
```

I want to hide all output I try many methods but can't work

Comment: You have edited this question to change it entirely, rendering the current answers nonsensical. Please revert this to it's original text and instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RobotFramework to mimic your actions in order to upload a Resume or Update your Profile.

You can use for eg. Selenium to automate the process in RobotFramework, or AWS to extract resume from S3.

There is support for a bunch of libraries to go for; https://robocorp.com/docs/libraries/rpa-framework

Answer (score 0):

Whilst Naukri has no publicly exposed API you could use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to control a browser instance and automate the process.

Comment: How to disable logs in selenium when I try to use it I get many logs in console

Comment: @rahul https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/04/disable-logging-in-selenium-chromedriver

Comment: It's not working 
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)